# The logarithmic inequality $\ln^q (1+x) \le \frac{q}{p} x^p \quad (x \ge 0, \; 0 < p \le q)$

Tags: inequality

$$\ln^q (1+x) \le \frac{q}{p} x^p \quad (x \ge 0, \; 0 < p \le q)$$

For $p=q$ this reduces to the familiar $\ln(1+x) \le x$. Otherwise I haven't had much success in proving it. General suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put $p=\frac{1}{\ln x}$ and when $x > e$ then $p <1$ and we arrive at

$\ln^q(x+1) \leq  q \ln x  * x^{p}$ which is $\ln^q (x+1) \leq q \ln x *e$

when $q \geq 2$ we get that $\ln^q(x+1) \leq e q \ln x$

Because  $\ln^q(x+1)\geq \ln^q x \geq e q \ln x$ divide by $\ln x$

We get that $\ln^{q-1} x \geq e q $ and since $q \geq 2$

then we have that $\ln^{q-1} x \geq \ln x \geq e q$ which will be true whenever

$\ln x \geq e q$ exponent -ate  both sides we get that

$x \geq e^{e q}$ for example if we put $q=3$ then the inequality will be false for all $ x \geq e^{3e} \approx 3480.2$

Comment: In your second line, how are you concluding that $x^p \le e$ based on $x>e$ and $0<p<1$?

Comment: no its equal to $e$ , $x^p = x^{\frac{1}{\ln x}} = e^{\frac{\ln x}{\ln x}} = e$ since every number $x$ can be written as $e^{\ln x}$.

Comment: Thank you. In the fourth line, the first inequality is by monotonicity of ln. The second one I'm puzzling over ...

Comment: the second one, i proved it the next few lines.

Comment: the idea is we need to come up with a counter-example since the inequality you posted "must work for all numbers x" , so at least one counter-example is sufficient to disprove your inequality.

Comment: Understood, just looking at your details. So is $p=1/2$, $q=3$, and $x=3500$ a counterexample then? Let me check ...

Comment: $p = \frac{1}{\ln x}$ so in this case $p=\frac{1}{\ln 3500} \approx 0.12254$, sure will be counter-example , for $p=\frac{1}{2}$ it might (not sure).

Comment: Yes, even $p=1/2$, $q=3$, $x=30$ seems to be a counterexample. I know I'm not supposed to thank people here, but the interaction with both you and @Shalop has been much appreciated.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 2):

This is false. If it were true, then for $q \geq 1$ we can set $p=1$ and we would have that $$\log(1+x) \leq q^{1/q} x^{1/q}$$ Then we can let $q \to \infty$ on both sides and we get that $\log(1+x) \leq 1$, which clearly becomes false as soon as $x >e-1$.

For an explicit counterexample, Wolfram alpha tells me that $\log^{50} 3 = 110.2...$ while $\frac{50}{1} \cdot 2^1 =\frac{50}{2} \cdot 2^2= 100$.

Comment: Interesting. The assertion appeared in a published paper. Are you confident that $\log^{50} 3$ is the computed value?

Comment: @NorthSpike Maybe there were additional assumptions which should be there? For example, the inequality is true for $x \leq (q/p)^{1/(q-p)}$

Comment: Possibly, but the paper does not put any other restrictions on $x$ or $q$.

Comment: I'm wary of raising machine numbers to huge powers without using validated numerics that also provide error bounds on the calculation. Not saying your $\approx 110$ is wrong, just that I'm wary.   :-)

Comment: @NorthSpike Okay, but what about the justification before that?

Comment: The paper does not specify $q<+\infty$, but possibly that was meant. So maybe we cannot pass to the limit as $q \to \infty$ here. Any  ideas if we agree that $q < +\infty$?